# Create custom button(s) for CKeditor 5 toolbar

Tags: javascript, button, plugins, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I've managed to customize the header and highlight dropdowns for [CKEditor 5 – classic editor build](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic) by creating a new [custom build](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/development/custom-builds.html).
But I don't know how to add additional buttons to the toolbar. For example a fullscreen button.
Current progress: [github link](https://github.com/barnatekse/ckeditor5-build-lateral/tree/stable)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to add existing buttons to the main toolbar, then you need to configure the [`config.toolbar`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_editor_editorconfig-EditorConfig.html#member-toolbar). In your example it corresponds to [these lines](https://github.com/barnatekse/ckeditor5-build-lateral/blob/4ae710265df432157f00c5912f51e1bc519cc6a8/src/ckeditor.js#L102-L119).

There's no fullscreen button at this moment. You can add +1 to the https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/1235 to increase its priority or try to implement this feature on your own.

Basically, to create your own button you need to create a plugin which registers the button in the component factory and adds some actions that will be performed on the `buttonView:execute` event. You can follow the steps described in [creating a simple plugin guide](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/plugins/creating-simple-plugin-timestamp.html).
A good and complementary reading about the UI library can be found [here](https://ckeditor5.github.io/docs/nightly/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/architecture/ui-library.html).

Comment: An example of what? Of how to create a toolbar button or how to add some existing button to the toolbar?

Comment: Of how to create a toolbar button.

Comment: I've expended my answer, you can check it.

Comment: Got it! Dziękuję Ci bardzo!